# Google Sheets: Formulas over multiple sheets

Tags: google-sheets

Is it possible to grab the contents of a cell from one sheet and display them on another?

I have 4 sheets. And I want the cells of the third sheet to display the first column of the second sheet on the second column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the sheetname exclamation point to your cell reference

e.g. sheet!A:1

Then drag from the first cell down to as many rows as you need.

Answer (score 3):

if you want to get range from another sheet just use:

> Replace 'Sheet' and 'A2:C8' with title and range you want to refer

```
={Sheet!A2:C8}
```

For multiple sheets

> Replace ';' with ',' for horizontal view:

```
={Sheet!A2:C8;Sheet1!A2:C8;Sheet2!A2:C8}
```

Answer (score 2):

Google Sheets allows reference between sheets. the syntax is pretty simple. consider a single cell: `=<sheetname>!A2` for example. From there, you can drag down with the bottom right corner, and your your column will now be a copy of an arbitrary column in , in this case A

Answer (score 2):

These are the annotations for cells in google sheets

`Sheetname!A:1` For Relative Cells
`Sheetname!$A:1` For Absolute Columns
`Sheetname!A:$1` For Absolute Rows
`Sheetname!$A:$1` For Absolute Cells

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  For specific ranges you can use `IMPORTRANGE`.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to grab the contents of a cell from one sheet and display them on another?

Yes. It's even possible to get entire columns of data.

In sheet 2 A1,

```
 =ARRAYFORMULA('Sheet1'!A:A)
```

The single quotes `'` can be omitted, if the sheet name doesn't have a space . In other words, if you use `Monthly Budget` as a sheet name, then single quotes is mandatory.