# Google Sheets formula to calculate total sum of values in from multiple columns in another sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query

I need a formula for cell B2 in Sheet1 which will calculate the total value of column B in Sheet2 where the value of column A in Sheet2 matches any URL's in columns C to E in Sheet1.

For example B2 in Sheet1 would total 43 (32 + 9 + 2 from B2 + B4 + B6 in Sheet2), B3 would total 4, B5 would total 4 etc etc.

Note: Sheet1 may sometimes have URL's in

Sheet1

[image]

Sheet2

[image]

Comment: Mmm, maybe you can find the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46006238/google-sheets-formulas-over-multiple-sheets)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

paste in **Sheet1!B2** and drag down:

```
=SUM(ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(TRANSPOSE(C2:2), Sheet2!A$2:B, 2, 0))))
```

[image: 0]